# Process Haskell list from right to left keeping origin order

Tags: list, haskell, iteration, reverse

Need increment every second item starting from the right in Haskell list but keeping origin order (e.g. `reverse` is not a case). For example:

```
 f [1, 2, 3] --  [1, 3, 3]

 f [1, 2, 3, 4] -- [2, 2, 4, 4]
```

I've tried something like a following:

```
fc ([]) = []
fc (x:[]) = [x]
fc (x:[y]) = [x+1,y]
fc( x:xs ) = fc [x] : ( fc xs ) -- this line is wrong
```

p.s. Obviously I could reverse (but prefer to understand original task) the list twice and apply something like:

```
helper (x:y:tail) = [x, y+1] ++ tail
fc x = reverse (helper (reverse x) )
```

Comment: Your second example is changing 1st and 3rd item. What's what you want to do?

Comment: @MASL the task is increase each 2'nd from right. So look at list from right: the second from right is `3->(3+1)=4`, now skip `2`, after that  4th `1->(1+1)=2`. So result `[2, 2, 4, 4]`

Comment: Ok. Oversaw that detail.

Comment: Reverse the list, add 1 to every second element and reverse to get the original order back.

Comment: @raymonad yep, it is possible, but I would like to understand how to process list from right-to-left, see my 'p.s.' update

Comment: Do you mean that you want to increment every second item starting from the right?

Comment: @Dewfy Please edit your question as to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done efficiently using a *left fold*:

```
inc :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
inc xs = foldl go (\_ _ acc -> acc) xs id (+ 1) []
    where go run x f g acc = run g f (f x: acc)
```

Note that even thought this is a left fold, the list is built using cons `(:)` operator; and it will perform linearly and not quadratic (similar construct as in [difference lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_list)).

```
\> inc [1, 2, 3]
[1,3,3]
\> inc [1, 2, 3, 4]
[2,2,4,4]
```

It can also be generalized to alternating functions other than `id` and `(+ 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to process a Haskell list from right to left would be to reverse it. Since you want to have the original order for the result, you would simply reverse again:

```
f1 = reverse . zipWith (+) (cycle [0,1]) . reverse
```

But if you really want to, you can have each recursive call return both the updated tail and a flag that indicates whether that position is even when counted from the end so you know whether to increase the element at that position or not:

```
f2 = snd . g
  where
  g []     = (False, [])
  g (x:xs) = let (addOne, xs') = g xs
                 x' = if addOne then x + 1 else x
             in (not addOne, x':xs')
```

We're basically mapping a function over the list, but this function requires an extra parameter that gets computed starting from the right end of the list. There's a standard function we can use:

```
import Data.List (mapAccumR)
f2' = snd . mapAccumR g False
  where
  g addOne x = (not addOne, if addOne then x + 1 else x)
```

Comment: I really like your second answer. Note that the two approaches may perform very differently. The double reverse will generally allocate quite a bit more memory, but only benchmarks can say which will really be better.

Answer (score 4):

I think a cleaner specification for what you want is that you increment even indicies if the length is even and odd indicies if the length is odd. For example, when indexing from zero, the list of length 3 resulted in index 1 being incremented.  One way to do this is with the obvious two pass solution:

```
f xs = zipWith (+) (cycle sol) xs
 where sol = map fromEnum [even len, odd len] 
       len = length xs
```

This can be done in one pass (without relying on the compiler fusion rules) by "tying the knot".  For example (using manual recursive style as means of communication).

```
f2 xs = let (isEven, result) = go isEven xs in result
 where
  go _ []     = (True,     [])
  go e (x:xs) = let (ne,rest) = go (not e) xs
                in (not ne, x+fromEnum e : rest)
```

Comment: Nice try! Indeed it gives correct result. My origin question was inspired by trying to find common parts in Prolog and Haskell . Prolog gives you 2 ways 'iteration' and 'recursion' to process list in any direction. So looking at Haskell I can see only `f (x:xs)` - the recursive way

Comment: I don't see how raymonad's answer ties a knot, per se.

Comment: @dfeuer Oops, I glanced too fast.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I like Thomas's solution. However, I think a simple `foldr` is enough here.

```
process = snd . foldr (\x (b,xs) -> (not b, x + fromEnum b:xs)) (False,[])
```

Comment: This is the same as raymonad's second answer, except that you've inlined `mapAccumR`.

Comment: It doesn't have to be conceptually different to count as an answer. Plus, I find `foldr` to be much easier to understand for beginners than `mapAccumR`, because it's much more widely used in functional languages.

Comment: I'll grant that, but the whole situation is a bit unusual. `mapAccumL` is much more common, and few beginners will understand its translation to `foldr`.